# jQuery floating animations - better ideas?

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm looking for a way to make my animations a bit smoother.

So I don't have to go to the lengths of explaininghave a look [here](http://brownbox.net.au/clients/amvi_new/) and play with the filtering options.

[image]

As you can see it animates... but not the best... It can be a bit jolty when things suddenly fadeOut completely.

Instead I would love them to slide up to their current positions... just like this: http://amvisydney.com.au/

So here is my current code for the animations (using fadeIn and fadeOut):

```
      if($(this).attr('rel').indexOf(amy) >= 0){

         $(this).fadeIn(500);

      }else{

         $(this).fadeOut(500);

      }
```

Let me know what I could do to improve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(this)..animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, 350);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/pWaMx/23/)

Comment: thanks for this - but it's not exactly what I'm after. I'm not talking about animating the information below it but rather what happens when you click the filter options... Go to the site I created and click on one of the director or content options... the big boxes hide and show in a not very nice way.